# ruby on windows: How to store an accented string in an environment variable and get it back intact

Tags: ruby, mingw32

When I save a string containing é in to a ENV variable, and then
get it back in ruby, it appears to be messed up. Am I doing something wrong?

To demonstrate, this script

```
require 'zlib'
puts "Encoding.default_external is #{Encoding.default_external}"
puts "Encoding.default_internal is #{Encoding.default_internal}"
puts "File.expand_path("") is #{File.expand_path("")}"
puts "File.expand_path("") size is #{File.expand_path("").size}"
puts "File.expand_path("").encoding is #{File.expand_path("").encoding}"
puts "File.expand_path("") checksum is #{Zlib::crc32(File.expand_path(""))}"
puts "Saving"
ENV['ABC'] = File.expand_path("")
puts "ENV['ABC'] is #{ENV['ABC']}"
puts "ENV['ABC'] size is #{ENV['ABC'].size}"
puts "ENV['ABC'].encoding is #{ENV['ABC'].encoding}"
puts "ENV['ABC'] checksum is #{Zlib::crc32(ENV['ABC'])}"
```

produces

```
C:\Users\Name\Nestlé\learn-rails>ruby test.rb
Encoding.default_external is IBM437
Encoding.default_internal is
File.expand_path() is C:/Users/Name/Nestlé/learn-rails
File.expand_path() size is 32
File.expand_path().encoding is UTF-8
File.expand_path() checksum is 1553489379
Saving
ENV['ABC'] is C:/Users/Name/NestlAc/learn-rails
ENV['ABC'] size is 35
ENV['ABC'].encoding is ASCII-8BIT
ENV['ABC'] checksum is 3711979874
C:\Users\Name\Nestlé\learn-rails>
```